Can HRV be filtered on the outgoing side? Ducted?
JThis may be two questions, but they're both about HRV airflow so let's try it this way...
I'm interested in eventually adding a Heat Recovery Ventilator (HRV) to my basement workshop, for fume extraction. But I'm a bit worried about accumulation of sawdust or other crud on the heat exchanger. I would hope there are ways to give that a periodic cleaning, but it might make sense to have the outgoing air run thru a filter first. Do HRVs have a standard way to use/adapt to a filter, or could I bodge something together by using ducting to draw inside air thru a filter without taking up half the workshop's space? (Despite allergies I'm much less concerned about filtering incoming air.)
Or am I being overly concerned?
Subsidiary question: if I can/do add ducting and filtering to the outgoing path... How obscene would it be to have this function as range hood exhaust too? Different types of crud, same desire to keep it off the heat exchange surfaces; more ducting and maybe a damper to select...
Or is the whole thing "one of your re-dickle-most ideas", and HRV only suitable for relatively clean spaces? (At least short of restaurant kitchens, where I could see a huge and/or specialized version being worth the investment.)
Exploring the boundaries of the design space, I presume... Seemed worth asking anyway.

Help out and old guy please.  HRV?  I thought that was a Honda.  and , (paraphrasing WK via ClaF, or vice versa),  ???

Good point. @rdman, definition added at start of question.

. The paraphrase is of a line spoken by the character Churchy LaFemme in the Pogo series of comic strips written and drawn by Walt Kelly; I wanted to acknowledge the source without digressing too far. Could add a footnote, I guess, or just a link

The phrase has, in Kelly's idiom, been lunk

There are absolutely ways to clean a HRV (Heat Recovery Ventilator)
If I were facing this situation, I would attach the HRV to a plenum and a return grill with a filter. That would be a simple setup with standard parts, and the large surface area of the return grill would minimize any pressure loss. The units are designed to work with long ducts, so they allow for pressure drop as part of the balancing.
